# Reading .tbl file python 3

Tags: python-3.x

I want to read a .tbl file in Python 3. I tried the following code according to https://penandpants.com/2012/03/09/reading-text-tables-with-python/

```
import numpy as np
dat = np.genfromtxt('myfile.tbl')
```

However, when I look at my file it reads   [`[ nan,  245.5,  160.3,  254.8 ]]`.

It should read [`[ SomeName,  245.5,  160.3,  254.8 ]]`

**Question:** How can I recover the original name? or is there a better way to load my `.tbl` data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import pandas
pandas.read_table('myfile.tbl', comment='#', delim_whitespace=True)
```