# Converting from .tbl to .csv format using python

Tags: python, csv, tbl

Trying to do some data analysis on some data but all downloaded data is in .tbl format and I would rather have it in .csv format. Is there a way to convert to .tbl to .csv through a python script.

Right now, I am uploading the files directly into excel which does the job but I need this process to be a bit quicker

Comment: `pandas` can read `.tbl` files. If you are doing data analysis you wouldn't even need to convert to csv as you could do everything in Python. Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46331935/reading-tbl-file-python-3).

Comment: Ok thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Hope this code snippet will help you.

```
def converttbldatatocsvformat(filename, header):
 csv = open("".join([path, filename, ".csv"]), "w+")
 csv.write(header + "\n")
 tbl = open("".join([path, filename, ".tbl"]), "r")
 lines = tbl.readlines()
 for line in lines:
    length = len(line)
    line = line[:length - 2] + line[length-1:]
    line = line.replace(",","N")
    line = line.replace("|",",")
    csv.write(line)
 tbl.close()
 csv.close()
```

Comment: Cool @RohanNagavardhan. Please let me know if you find any issue.